# Using case statement in SQL server or Oracle

Tags: sql

I have modified my requirement for task#2. I was wondering if someone could help me out. I tried to get the sum from the ITEM column where the records are not in task #1 and task #3.

Thank you very much.

I created a simple table and some raw data. I have tried to do the following tasks:

1. a.Sum the records contain 'FIRA' as FIRA. 
   b.Sum the records contain 'FMUA' as FMUA. 
   c.Sum the records contain 'SOTA' as SOTA. 
   d.Sum the records contain 'PERA' as PERA. 
   e.Sum the records contain 'SGDA' as SGDA. 
   f.Sum the records contain 'TGDA' as TGDA. 
   h.Sum the records contain 'CRMA' as CRMA.
2. Sum the records that are not from task #1 and task #3 AS MULTIPLE_CLASSIFICATION.
3. Sum the remaining records that are not from #1 and #2 above as NONE_CLASSIFICATION.

I was able to complete task #1 and #3 but unable to complete task #2
Below is my query tested in SQL Server and Oracle.

```
CREATE TABLE TEMP
(
  CLASSIFICATION VARCHAR (100),
  ITEM           INTEGER
)

insert into temp values ('CRMA', 66);
insert into temp values ('FIRA', 1288);
insert into temp values ('FIRA/ATEPT/DR', 3);
insert into temp values ('DR/SERA/ATEPT/FIRA', 4);
insert into temp values ('PERA', 1311);
insert into temp values ('STATE/SERA/PERA/ERS', 1);
insert into temp values ('null', 136);
insert into temp values ('PERA/DR/ATEPT', 4);
insert into temp values ('SOTA', 1);
insert into temp values ('FERA/SOTA', 1);
insert into temp values ('SOTA/SATO/DT', 1);
insert into temp values ('FMUA', 5);
insert into temp values ('SERA', 8);
insert into temp values ('SGDA', 3);
insert into temp values ('TGDA', 1);
insert into temp values ('TGDA/ATPET', 1);
insert into temp values ('ATPET', 15);
insert into temp values ('CRMA/PERA', 2);
insert into temp values ('SERA/FIRA/ATEPT/SGDA/SGD', 5);
insert into temp values ('FIRE/FIRA/SERA/DR/SOTA', 4)

-----------------------TASK #1--------------------------

SELECT
SUM (CASE WHEN CLASSIFICATION LIKE '%FIRA%'
AND CLASSIFICATION NOT LIKE '%CRMA%'
AND CLASSIFICATION NOT LIKE '%FMUA%'
AND CLASSIFICATION NOT LIKE '%SOTA%'  
AND CLASSIFICATION NOT LIKE '%PERA%'
AND CLASSIFICATION NOT LIKE '%SGDA%'
AND CLASSIFICATION NOT LIKE '%TGDA%' THEN ITEM END) AS FIRA,

SUM (CASE WHEN CLASSIFICATION LIKE '%FMUA%'
AND CLASSIFICATION NOT LIKE '%FIRA%'
AND CLASSIFICATION NOT LIKE '%CRMA%'
AND CLASSIFICATION NOT LIKE '%SOTA%'
AND CLASSIFICATION NOT LIKE '%PERA%'
AND CLASSIFICATION NOT LIKE '%SGDA%'
AND CLASSIFICATION NOT LIKE '%TGDA%' THEN ITEM END) AS FMUA,

SUM (CASE WHEN CLASSIFICATION LIKE '%SOTA%'
AND CLASSIFICATION NOT LIKE '%FIRA%'
AND CLASSIFICATION NOT LIKE '%CRMA%'
AND CLASSIFICATION NOT LIKE '%FMUA%'
AND CLASSIFICATION NOT LIKE '%PERA%'
AND CLASSIFICATION NOT LIKE '%SGDA%'
AND CLASSIFICATION NOT LIKE '%TGDA%' THEN ITEM END) AS SOTA,

SUM (CASE WHEN CLASSIFICATION LIKE '%PERA%'
AND CLASSIFICATION NOT LIKE '%FIRA%'
AND CLASSIFICATION NOT LIKE '%CRMA%'
AND CLASSIFICATION NOT LIKE '%FMUA%'
AND CLASSIFICATION NOT LIKE '%SOTA%'
AND CLASSIFICATION NOT LIKE '%SGDA%'
AND CLASSIFICATION NOT LIKE '%TGDA%' THEN ITEM END) AS PERA,

SUM (CASE WHEN CLASSIFICATION LIKE '%SGDA%'
AND CLASSIFICATION NOT LIKE '%FIRA%'
AND CLASSIFICATION NOT LIKE '%FMUA%'
AND CLASSIFICATION NOT LIKE '%SOTA%'
AND CLASSIFICATION NOT LIKE '%PERA%'
AND CLASSIFICATION NOT LIKE '%TGDA%'
AND CLASSIFICATION NOT LIKE '%CRMA%' THEN ITEM END) AS SGDA,

SUM (CASE WHEN CLASSIFICATION LIKE '%TGDA%'
AND CLASSIFICATION NOT LIKE '%FIRA%'
AND CLASSIFICATION NOT LIKE '%FMUA%'
AND CLASSIFICATION NOT LIKE '%SOTA%'
AND CLASSIFICATION NOT LIKE '%PERA%'
AND CLASSIFICATION NOT LIKE '%SGDA%'
AND CLASSIFICATION NOT LIKE '%CRMA%' THEN ITEM END) AS TGDA,

SUM (CASE WHEN CLASSIFICATION LIKE '%CRMA%'
AND CLASSIFICATION NOT LIKE '%FIRA%'
AND CLASSIFICATION NOT LIKE '%FMUA%'
AND CLASSIFICATION NOT LIKE '%SOTA%'
AND CLASSIFICATION NOT LIKE '%PERA%'
AND CLASSIFICATION NOT LIKE '%SGDA%'
AND CLASSIFICATION NOT LIKE '%TGDA%' THEN ITEM END) AS CRMA,

-----------------------TASK #2--------------------------
SUM (CASE WHEN ( CLASSIFICATION LIKE '%FIRA%'
OR CLASSIFICATION LIKE '%FMUA%'
OR CLASSIFICATION LIKE '%SOTA%'
OR CLASSIFICATION LIKE '%PERA%'
OR CLASSIFICATION LIKE '%SGDA%'
OR CLASSIFICATION LIKE '%TGDA%'
OR CLASSIFICATION LIKE '%CRMA%') THEN ITEM END) AS MULIPLE_CLASSIFICATIONS,

-----------------------TASK #3--------------------------
SUM (CASE WHEN ( CLASSIFICATION NOT LIKE '%FIRA%'
AND CLASSIFICATION NOT LIKE '%FMUA%'
AND CLASSIFICATION NOT LIKE '%SOTA%'
AND CLASSIFICATION NOT LIKE '%PERA%'
AND CLASSIFICATION NOT LIKE '%SGDA%'
AND CLASSIFICATION NOT LIKE '%TGDA%'
AND CLASSIFICATION NOT LIKE '%CRMA%') THEN ITEM END) AS NONE_CLASSIFICATIONS
FROM TEMP

FIRA    FMUA    SOTA    PERA    SGDA    TGDA    CRMA    MULIPLE_CLASSIFICATIONS NONE_CLASSIFICATIONS

  1295  5     3       1316    3          2       66      2701                      159
```

Answer (score 0):

Your task 2 includes "FIRA", which has a value of 1288. Since 1288 is greater than the total sum that you're expecting, your sum query should be revised to only include the types of values that you're looking for. See your insert:

```
insert into temp values ('FIRA', 1288);
```

and your query:

```
--for task #2
SUM (CASE WHEN ( CLASSIFICATION LIKE '%FIRA%'
OR CLASSIFICATION LIKE '%FMUA%'
OR CLASSIFICATION LIKE '%SOTA%'
OR CLASSIFICATION LIKE '%PERA%'
OR CLASSIFICATION LIKE '%SGDA%'
OR CLASSIFICATION LIKE '%TGDA%'
OR CLASSIFICATION LIKE '%CRMA%') THEN ITEM END) AS MULIPLE_CLASSIFICATIONS,
```

Comment: Thank you. I expect to sum up the last three records from the inserted records above which 11.